# preg_replace to remove multiple <a href> elements

Tags: php, html-parsing

probably it's something easy for most of you, but I've been strugling to replace all `<a href="url">` anything `</a>` from a string.

Can someone help me out with this and give me some pointers with documentations and examples? The php.net doesn't help much, struggling to understand.

From what I realize I need to replace:

```
'<a href=*' up until the '>' character is met.
```

Replacing the `</a>` I can manage :)

Comment: Your solution is going to fail if the tag spans two lines, which is perfectly legitimate.  The safest thing to do is use a proper HTML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be simpler, but given the requirements and not knowing of any variations in your string:

```
$new = preg_replace('/<a href=[^>]+>/', '', str_replace('</a>', '', $string));
```

Comment: sorry, my bad, It was something wrong I did :) THANKS! Also, where can I find simple examples of preg_replace, other than in php.net? I can't understand a thing there...

Comment: But, `strip_tags` would be preferred if you don't have lots of or unknown tags that you want to keep.

Answer (score 3):

What would be wrong with using the [strip_tags](http://www.php.net/strip_tags) function in PHP? Are you absolutely trying to use a regular expression (something I would advise against when working with HTML)?

The PHP documentation example does just what you want:

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

Results:

```
Test paragraph. Other text
<p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>
```

Comment: +1. Unless OP has a very specific reason not to use `strip_tags()`, this is the best solution.

Comment: The only thing I want removed is the tags but keep the content between them. This seems to strip everything.

Comment: The content is actually preserved (look carefully at the output of the example). The link text "Other text" is output with no problem, showing that the tag and its attributes are removed, but the inner content is saved.

Comment: I suppose this could work as well. :/ I had <img> tags between the <a></a> so I guess allowing <p><img> might do the trick but the above solution works better for me. thanks for your efforts :)